# Having issue with Xcode 7 iOS 9 mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, ios-9-beta5

I am building a sample application using Xcode 7 beta6. I have included MapView in xib and a label . When I am trying to run the app it is giving the below error. It is working in Xcode 6. I have searched web but nothing is working for me. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is of help to you as I am in a similar issue with XCode 7 and iOS 9 whereas it was working for me too in iOS 8.4 and XCode 6.4... But I previously had to make two inserts into the info.plist section of XCode of the app in order for my app using a UIMapview to work.  I just discovered it yesterday myself iwhen I upgraded to iOS 9 and XCod4 7.  Hope this points you in a general correct direction to look.

Comment: What keys/values I have to insert in the info.plist?